# Error occurs after import LibGdx project to java

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I wanted to start game development with ***LibGdx*** and ***Java***, my IDE - ***Eclipse***, but some problems have occured.I see little red icon with white cross under project folder in Eclipse.The full **error**:

> "Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput." .

I was updating Eclipse(now it is the latest release), reinstalling jdk, sdk and gradle.My java version is **"12.0.1"** and gradle - **5.4.1**

```
    task dist(type: Jar) {
      from files(sourceSets.getClassesDirs());
      from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
      from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
      from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
      attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
```

I just want to run projects on LibGdx with Eclipse and this error **be gone,**
Thanks.

Comment: In desktop/build.gradle change the line `from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)` to `from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)`

Comment: And in my personal opinion, it is highly painful to use a gradle-based project in Eclipse. I used to have many very time-consuming build-errors to fix, and it was practically life-changing to switch to IntelliJ IDEA.